# iphone change tab bar item on button click

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 4 tabs in my iphone application. When user will click a button in tab-1, I want to move/switch user to another tab suppose tab-2.

How to do that?

Comment: You don't click buttons on the iPhone, you tap them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:tabIndex];
```

where `tabIndex` is the index of the tab you want to switch to.

Comment: and how to check which tab is clicked? any delegate method?

Comment: When switching tabs, the `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` delegate method will be called. All of this is available in the documentation. It took me less than a minute to find it and answer your question ;)

Answer (score 3):

Might also point out that if you are inside a view, you should use super instead of self.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 version of @Jasarien answer:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = tabIndex
```

where `tabIndex` is the index of the tab you want to switch to.